# mysql complex query for monthly report

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

employee makes entry in the following table when starting new task
from home or office

```
[tablename=CHECK]
c_id   c_sdate                c_emp       c_task
-------------------------------------------------
1     2013-05-01 01:01:00       1           26    //date 01 from home-----
2     2013-05-01 08:11:00       1           27    //date 01 from office--- Present

3     2013-05-02 03:41:00       1           28    //date 02 from home---
4     2013-05-02 09:12:00       1           29    //date 02 from office-
5     2013-05-02 22:32:00       1           30    //date 02 from home---Present

6     2013-05-03 01:43:00       1           31    //date 03 from home
7     2013-06-03 23:25:00       1           32    //date 03 from home----------Homework

8     2013-06-03 02:15:00       2           33    //other employee
```

an employe will be considered as present if there 1 or many records where time between 8am and 8pm

an employe will be considered as workedFromHome if there 1 or many records where time NOT between 8am and 8pm, and not present on that day
   **note:** do not count a day as workedFromHome if there is any record   time between 8am and 8pm (means workedFromHome is only counted if he is not resent on that day)

> I want to display monthly report of a employee eg. c_emp=1 for month eg. 5
>   like this in 1 query

```
c_emp  presentCount   HW_Count
  1       3             1
```

or separatly query 1

```
c_emp  presentCount  
  1       3
```

and query 2

```
c_emp   HW_Count
  1        1
```

I have tried for counting present working fine

```
select count(distinct(date_format(c_sdate,'%e'))) as count 
from ita_check
where date_format(c_sdate,'%m')=5 
and c_emp=1 
and date_format(c_sdate,'%H%i')>=800
and date_format(c_sdate,'%H%i')<=2000
```

and for counting fromHome giving wrong count

```
select count(distinct(date_format(c_sdate,'%e'))) as count 
from ita_check
where date_format(c_sdate,'%m')=5
and c_eid=1
and c_id not in (
   select c_id 
   from ita_check
   where date_format(c_sdate,'%m')=5 
   and c_eid=1
   and (date_format(c_sdate,'%H%i')<=800 or date_format(c_sdate,'%H%i')>=2000)
)
and date_format(c_sdate,'%H%i')<800
or date_format(c_sdate,'%H%i')>2000
```

in above query for counting Working
the sub query returns 1 and 2
while the outer eliminate c_id=2 but not c_id=1

Comment: Have you tried anything then show us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT c_emp, 
sum(if(cnt>=1,1,0)) as Office, 
count(*)-sum(if(cnt>=1,1,0)) as WFH   from (
select c_emp, Date(c_sdate),
sum(if(c_sdate BETWEEN Date(c_sdate) + interval 8 hour 
       AND Date(c_sdate) + interval 20 hour, 1, 0)) as cnt
from table1
group by c_emp, Date(c_sdate)) tmp
group by c_emp
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0828/9)**:

```
| C_EMP | OFFICE | WFH |
------------------------
|     1 |      2 |   2 |
|     2 |      0 |   1 |
```

For monthly report

```
SELECT c_emp, date_format(c_date, '%c %Y') as Mnth,
sum(if(cnt>=1,1,0)) as Office, 
count(*)-sum(if(cnt>=1,1,0)) as WFH   from (
select c_emp, Date(c_sdate) as c_date,
sum(if(c_sdate BETWEEN Date(c_sdate) + interval 8 hour 
       AND Date(c_sdate) + interval 20 hour, 1, 0)) as cnt
from table1
group by c_emp, Date(c_sdate)) tmp
group by c_emp,Mnth
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0828/14)**:

```
| C_EMP |   MNTH | OFFICE | WFH |
---------------------------------
|     1 | 5 2013 |      2 |   1 |
|     1 | 6 2013 |      0 |   1 |
|     2 | 6 2013 |      0 |   1 |
```